# Sending string using POST in Corona

Tags: php, android, post, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to send data to PHP using a POST request in Corona SDK.
This data is extremely simple, i.e. a single line string.

The example given in the Corona documentation involves custom headers, and sending some sort of encoded data which I don't understand or need. I tried sending a single string with Post, but it does not work. My code is:

```
local widget = require("widget")
local url = 'examplewebsite'


local function networkListener(query)
    if ( query.isError ) then
        print( "Network error!", query.response )
    else
        print ( "RESPONSE: " .. query.response )
    end
end


local function query()
    local params = {"hey"}
    print("Sending Request to Server...")
    network.request(url,"POST",networkListener,params)
end

local request_button = widget.newButton
{
    label = "SQL Request",
    left = 60,
    top = 230,
    fontSize = 35,
    onRelease = query
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
local function query()
    local params = {
        body = "message=hey"
    };
    print("Sending Request to Server...")
    network.request(url,"POST",networkListener, params)
end
```

and in PHP side you should get

```
__POST["message"] == "hey"
```